# Use Goto and From to Transfer Fcn block

Tags: simulink, goto, transfer-function

I have made a block in Simulink that calculates some Aerodynamic coefficients.

I had like to use this coefficients in order to define the numerator and denominator of a transfer function.

Is there a way to link between the output from the coefficients block to the transfer function?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is badly titled - it has nothing to do with GoTo and From.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The output of your aerodynamic block are *signals*. The numerator and denominator of the `Transfer Function` are *parameters*.  You cannot use signals as parameters, or vice-versa.

What you can do is construct your own transfer function using an appropriate arrangement of `Sum`, `Product` and `Integrator` blocks, with the signals from your aerodynamics block being used (typically in conjunction with the `Product` blocks) to define the appropriate coefficients/gains.

Comment: Thank you, will try to construct it.

Comment: Or @benb could create their own masked subsystem where the parameters passed to the aerodynamic block are also output from the block. This should be easy to configure.